# Social Distancing Colors - A New Type of Puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, strategy, grid-deduction

I think I just thought of a new type of puzzle:
Social Distancing Colors.

Each of the colors in the rainbow represents at least how much one has to distance by:

Red is 6m,
Orange is 5m,
Yellow is 4m,
Green is 3m,
Blue is 2m,
Indigo is 1m,
and Purple doesn’t need to distance.

Each meter is a square on a 10x10 board.
A Question would give a certain quantity for each color.

You calculate distances by calculating the shortest possible route between two colors and calculating the square count between one to the other.

For example: 2 Purples, 1 Blue, and 4 Yellows, and a solution could look like this:

[image]

If multiple types of colors are in a puzzle, two colors must have a minimum distance of the distance of the color with the most distance value between the two.

And obviously, a problem must be possible to solve.

That’s all the rules. Comment any questions and I’ll try to answer them. Happy puzzling!

Comment: Hi juicyguyzer - welcome to Puzzling :) You will probably need to refine the rules somehow to ensure there is only ONE solution to any individual puzzle, which can be deduced *logically*. Otherwise it would not be considered a workable puzzle type by normal definitions. If the aim is to place colours in the grid, perhaps also include 'dead spaces' where colours cannot be placed, or other obstacles/restrictions like this. The alternative of having certain squares in the board already placed and asking what colour they are would be trivial, so maybe don't go down that route. See what you can do!

Comment: So, what's the question here, exactly? Questions asked are expected to be actual *questions* that can be answered - either questions about puzzles, or a puzzle that can be answered by a solution. I may be misunderstanding, but it looks like the purpose of this is just to tell us about a puzzle mechanic you came up with.

Comment: If you’ve come up with a new puzzle type, a great way to introduce it is to design a puzzle! It doesn’t have to be especially challenging, and it will usually be helpful to know if it’s feasible to create many of the type. More specific to your puzzle type, it seems that the use of colours is to provide information that numbers could do in a more natural way